# Why is Angular converting string parameter to array?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a function that subscribes to a service that gets a folder's data from an API. Inside the function looks something like this:

```
this.galleryService.getGalleryFolderByName(this.clientId, folder_name).subscribe(
    (result) => {
        let data = result.data;
        if (data) {
            console.log(data)
        }...
    }
)
```

In the galleryService, getGalleryFolderByName has the following code:

```
getGalleryFolderByName(clientId: string|number, params: any) {
    return this.http.get<any>(GET_GALLERY_FOLDER_BY_NAME(clientId), {params: params});
}
```

In my local the API request has this URL in the network:
`folder?name=Sample%20Folder`

But when I merged it to the dev branch the URL now shows something like this:
`folder?0=S&1=a&2=m&3=p&4=l&5=e&6=%20&7=F&8=o&9=l&10=d&11=e&12=r`

Is this something to do with Angular version? I can't really find any difference between the files in my local and the dev server.

I created a branch in my local for dev and pulled the dev server, this branch also has the issue with the dev server, but when I checkout to my working branch it has the right parameters to the API.

Comment: Here's what I would do to debug this: Right before the call to `this.galleryService.getGalleryFolderByName` add `console.log(typeof folder_name, folder_name)`

Comment: For debugging you can also use `debugger;` and have the dev. tools of your browser open. You can then inspect the state/values of your application.

Comment: It shows string when I console.log the type of folder_name

Comment: So the value of `folder_name` is `"string"`?? Keep in mind that we cannot see your computer or the values you see. It is important to include *all* of the information in your question so we can best help you.

Comment: I modified the getGalleryFolderByName function to this:

    getGalleryFolderByName(clientId: string|number, params: any) {
        return this.http.get<any>(GET_GALLERY_FOLDER_BY_NAME(clientId), {params});
        let options = params ? { params: new HttpParams().set('name', params) } : {};
        return this.http.get<any>(GET_GALLERY_FOLDER_BY_NAME(clientId), options);
    }

and it solved the problem. Thank you very much @ChrisBarr and Igor